# Unnecessary LEFT JOINs on all Child tables from main LEFT JOIN table required in query for correct result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am `LEFT JOIN`-ing the table `RECALLS_T` with `EVENTS_T`. Some Recalls do not have any Events, and for those I want a blank row returned.

However, once an entry in `EVENTS_T` exists, all the following extra tables from `EVENTS_T` which I also need (`ANSWERS_T`, `ACTIVITY_QUESTIONS_T`, `ACTIVITES_T`) are **guaranteed** to have entries. For these subsequent tables there is no need to do a `LEFT JOIN` from their parent, it can be an `INNER JOIN` just as well.

But if I do the following, the query does not return blank `EVENTS_T` rows for a `RECALLS_T`.

```
SELECT ..
FROM 
   recalls_t r
   LEFT JOIN events_t e  ON ( r.id = e.recall_id )     --Only LEFT JOIN this main table
   INNER JOIN answers_t ans ON (ans.event_id = e.id)
   INNER JOIN activity_questions_t aq ON (ans.activity_question_id = aq.id)    
   INNER JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t act ON (aq.activity_id = act.id)
```

Instead, I need to change every subsequent `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` as well, in order to get Recalls with blank Events.

```
SELECT ..
FROM 
   recalls_t r
   LEFT JOIN events_t e  ON ( r.id = e.recall_id )     
   LEFT JOIN answers_t ans ON (ans.event_id = e.id)
   LEFT JOIN activity_questions_t aq ON (ans.activity_question_id = aq.id)    
   LEFT JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t act ON (aq.activity_id = act.id)
```

I'm just not clear on why I have to do this. The top-level optional join is all I care about, but the downstream joins from `EVENTS_T` are guaranteed to have data provided the Event exists. Shouldn't the top-level single `EVENTS_T` join be enough? I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need to do this is because rows preserved by the outer join will have `NULL` for all columns from `events` - so inner joining using an equality condition on `e.id` will remove them from the result again.

you can move the `ON` clause to the end of the query to give your desired semantics.

The left join is then on the virtual result of inner joining `events_t`, `answers_t`, `activity_questions_t` and `activities_t`

```
SELECT ...
FROM   recalls_t r
       LEFT JOIN events_t e
                 INNER JOIN answers_t ans
                         ON ( ans.event_id = e.id )
                 INNER JOIN activity_questions_t aq
                         ON ( ans.activity_question_id = aq.id )
                 INNER JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t act
                         ON ( aq.activity_id = act.id )
              ON ( r.id = e.recall_id )
```

Or you could consider a `RIGHT JOIN` here instead

```
SELECT ...
FROM   events_t e
       INNER JOIN answers_t ans
               ON ( ans.event_id = e.id )
       INNER JOIN activity_questions_t aq
               ON ( ans.activity_question_id = aq.id )
       INNER JOIN PUBLIC.activities_t act
               ON ( aq.activity_id = act.id )
       RIGHT JOIN recalls_t r
               ON ( r.id = e.recall_id )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this because ``` answers_t`` is joining on ```events_s`.  If the`join`key (`e.recall_id`) is`NULL`, then there will be no match.  And the inner join will not return the row.  And so on for the other tables.

You seem to understand the fix.  Once you use `left join`, you need to continue using `left join` for those tables that are connected to the second table of the `left join`.

Comment: But my question is, why not stop the LEFT requirement for subsequent tables? As as self-contained group, they do not require LEFT JOINs because there is no missing data.

Comment: @geneb. . . . There is no "requirement".  `LEFT JOIN` does one thing.  `[INNER] JOIN` does something else.  SQL assumes you will choose the `JOIN` that expresses what you want to do.